# need a help in reading an XML file from a project folder

Tags: java, xml

I need a help in reading an XML file from a project folder.

My Directory structure is:

```
Projectname: Test2
src dir :    Test2/src/bin
Resource to be read: Test2/xml/matrix.xml
```

Currently I'm using the following line of code to read, but I've no good luck with this.

```
String url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/xml/matrix.xml").getPath();
```

I encounter a nullpointer exception.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to untangle the train wreck. Go step by step: which method still works and which throws the NPE?

Comment: I want to use "this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/xml/matrix.xml").getPath();" and this throws NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("../xml/matrix.xml").getPath();
```

Comment: Hi Gefrag, thanks for ur response. But that is not working :( any other possibilities ???

Comment: If I use as "new File("xml/matrix.xml");

Comment: If I use as "new File("xml/matrix.xml"); I could read the file. But the same is failing when I use the ClassLoader functionalities ??

Comment: Make sure that the xml file is a classpath resource. Take a look at this article and things will be more clear. http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html